# How can I improve the Performance (response time) for the AWS Encryption SDK on decrypt

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda that is used to encrypt PII (Personal Identifying Information) using the AWS Encryption SDK before storing it in DynamoDB.

When retrieving the data from DynamoDB using a different Lambda to display to end users, the average time for each call to KMS is 9.48sec. This is averaged across roughly 2k requests with requests ranging from ~14.5 seconds to ~5.1 seconds. The calls to KMS are being made asynchronously.

The total time from the first KMS call to the last is ~20 seconds

We have considered using [data key caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/data-key-caching.html) and read [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/aws-encryption-sdk-how-to-decide-if-data-key-caching-is-right-for-your-application/) about when to use it.

The input of our data may not be frequent enough to take full advantage of caching, and I am trying to find other ways to improve the performance.

Decrypt Code Sippet:

```
async function decryptWithKeyring(keyring: KmsKeyringNode, ciphertext: string, context: {}) {
    const b: Buffer = Buffer.from(ciphertext, 'base64');
    const { plaintext, messageHeader } = await decrypt(keyring, b);
    const { encryptionContext } = messageHeader;
    Object.entries(context).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (encryptionContext[key] !== value) {
            throw new Error('Encryption Context does not match expected values');
        }
    });
    return plaintext.toString();
}
```

Encrypt Snippet:

```
async function encryptWithKeyring(keyring: KmsKeyringNode, value: any, context: any) {
    const { result } = await encrypt(keyring, value, { encryptionContext: context });
    return result.toString('base64');
}
```

The conversion to base64 was to facilitate storing in DynamoDB.

[XRay Trace Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2HOc.png)
[Sampling of KMS Trace data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7gFm.png)